# Logitech T650 not working correctly with 15.04 upgrade

Tags: touchpad, 15.04, logitech

With an in place upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04, the behavior of the mouse has changed in the following ways:

- 3 finger click (middle click) no longer works
- 3 and 4 finger drag no longer works.
- 2 finger scrolling is unreliable (too sensitive)
- 1 finger drag sometimes acts like I've clicked and held things (moves icons)

Everything is off in Universal access, I've tried all manner of adjustments in Mouse and Touchpad settings and I wasn't using any programs before that modified behavior.
Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logitech t650 wireless touchpad gestures](http://askubuntu.com/questions/614848/logitech-t650-wireless-touchpad-gestures)

Answer (score 1):

At present there isn't a solution, I too use a t650 and whilst it worked fine in 14.10 it doesn't in 15.04, which I'm now using again as I had to upgrade to solve an unrelated issue, I did ask a question on here a few days ago and this is the answer I got as to why the touchpad is no longer working as it was.

> In kernel 3.19 (as included with Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid) the Logitech HID++ >driver got rewritten to improve support for certain Logitech devices. This >shifted processing of events from the hardware (the touchpad) to software >(the Linux input driver stack).
>
> This results in the Logitech T650 touchpad not sending keyboard events such >as Back for three fingers. Since there is no multi-touch driver that >processes gestures, you do not get the event either.
>
> Workarounds:

```
Install a kernel version before 3.19 (or just the hid-logitech-dj driver from previous versions).
Enable both reporting of gestures as well as raw events. Since the events reporting is very sluggish after this method, I won't explain it here.
```

> A forward solution should recognize the multi-touch functionality of the >Logitech T650 touchpad and then generate appropriate events for gestures.

I am experiencing the same issues as you, I've also noticed that the right click button doesn't seem to do anything either,over all the touchpad is barely usable on my system, installing

> gpointing-device-settings

seems to give more options for tweaking the touchpad, but doesn't restore the functions that no longer work, and in all honesty for me it didn't improve the performance of the touchpad.

Edit :

Since writing this I have been doing some experimenting, and I have found at least for me a way to get 3 fingered swiping, I basically use it for browser navigation, but with more tweaking it might be possible to get a lot more of the touchpads functions working.

After searching I came across this - [multitouch gestures](http://blog.mpiannucci.com/view/multitouchgesture) it's taken a bit of messing about with, but that's more my lack of knowledge than anything else, I did have some issues when running some of the commands (specifically the make commands) turns out this might be down to glibc, but I found that using this source solved the make issues [clone from here if having make issues](https://github.com/dieghen89/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics)

I still have some issues with the touchpad, but this seems to be a step in the right direction, hope it helps.

Edit : I'm currently running ubuntu 16.04 and have up until recently not had much luck getting this touch pad to work in a useful way, but the other day I came across libinput-gestures - https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures

I found it easy to set up and works well, some putting it here as people may find it useful.