# Logitech Touchpad T650 problem: working fine on Ubuntu 14.10, but not on any other later version

Tags: touchpad, logitech

I am having a major difficulty with my Logitech T650 touchpad in the newer versions of Xubuntu.

On all (x)Ubuntu versions afterward 14.10 till the recent version 16.04 (except 14.10 itself), the touch pad is almost "useless", because the response time for click is so short. The touchpad is very sensitive to placing finger on the touchpad. So that moving the mouse pointer is mostly received as (1) tap (2) move, rather than just move. So it mostly select-drags rather than just move the mouse pointer.

For the scrolling with double finger gesture the two fingers touches the touchpad is received as double click instead most of the time. If I do the gesture really quick I might be able to scroll, otherwise it is so unreliable to scroll a page and mostly ends up double clicking.

Scrolling a page itself is slow and short, so I have to scroll many times to move a page down/up.

I do not have this problem in Xubuntu 14.10. But since from 2014, I have tried "all" Xubuntu versions, and they all have this issue. This problem even exists in the newer updates of earlier Xubuntu 14.04. I have tested Ubuntu as well, and this problem exists on all versions of Ubuntu later than 14.10.

This has been reported already in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/746069/how-to-fix-accidental-click-drags-with-logitech-t650-touchpad) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615370/logitech-t650-not-working-correctly-with-15-04-upgrade), and still I did not find any solution. I am still using version 14.10 just because of this issue, but I am willing to use newer versions. Is there a way to fix this issue? I want to make sure whether anyone found a solution before throwing out this touchpad and get other brands. I have two of this touch pad, and it is a really nice touchpad, I am trying to keep it and ask for a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get the "old" behavior (before kernel 3.19) you can create `/etc/modprobe.d/logitech-t650.conf` containing:

```
options hid_logitech_hidpp disable_raw_mode=1
```

Then either reboot or reload the module. This will prevent the driver from enabling "raw mode" which would make the driver responsible for processing touch events and instead rely on the touchpad itself to do touch event processing.

You can also try newer Ubuntu versions (with newer libinput), or try to play with the xinput/libinput properties on more recent versions of Ubuntu (using `xinput list-props "Logitech Rechargeable Touchpad T650"` and `xinput set-prop "Logitech Rechargeable Touchpad T650" ...`, see [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput)).